# New to R and focusing on project based learning. Attempting something that should be simple and running into difficulties with ggplot2

Tags: r

I'm working on a project that shows traffic hazards/accidents in the Charlotte, NC area. In a basic way, I'm wanting to show the relationship (positive or negative) with the data. I've tried using ggplot2 with date of incident vs event hoping it would show me a line graph with the dates along the x axis and the event numbers over the y, but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm thinking it's something simple that I'm not doing and hopefully someone can look at it really quickly and help me figure this out. The data set is located here: 
https://www.kaggle.com/rapiddev/charlotte-nc-traffic-accidents-20182019

I didn't want to attach it as it's a fairly large file. Truly, any help would be great.

```
ggplot(accidents,aes(x = event_no, y = datetime_add, color = event_desc)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

That's what I was working with, but I was running into issues with the date/time variable. I saw one of the commenters mention the lubridate package from TIDYR, so I tried that as well. If there was a way to do a basic line graph of dates showing growth or decline using those variables. The only problem I was running into is the event_no is a char type with the 's' being in the number itself. I wasn't sure if there was a way to just use each of the rows, since they're incidents in of themselves, compared to the date/time.

Comment: Add a code example please. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach with `lubridate` to process the dates and `dplyr` for data processing:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
data <- fromJSON("accidents.json", flatten = TRUE)
data %>% 
  dplyr::select(event_no, datetime_add, event_desc) %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(ymd_hms(datetime_add))) %>%
  group_by(date, event_desc) %>%
  summarise(events = n()) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = date, y = events, color = event_desc)) +
  geom_line() + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.text = element_text(size = 5)) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(nrow = 3)) +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Number of Events", color = "Description")
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the help. I haven't had a lot of experience with lubridate. Thanks for posting!

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stack overflow and trying to figure everything out. Thanks again for the help Ian!